# RabbitMQ loses configuration after upgrade

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, upgrade

After performing an upgrade of a two node cluster from RabbitMQ `3.6.15` to `3.7.9` (er documentation this is supported directly - no intermediate version upgrade), along with updating Erlang from `18.7.3` to latest `21.10.1.1`, `rabbitmq-server` won't start on the "upgrader" node:

```
systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

journalctl -xe says

```
attempted to contact: ['rabbit@upd-web']
rabbit@upd-web:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on upd-web
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on upd-web
  * suggestion: start the node
Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-3561-rabbit@upd-web'
 * effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
 * Erlang cookie hash: iGIHB+jl59ul7YFrqAFIZQ==
```

The problem is that after upgrade, rabbit tries to connect to another local node, different from the one that was configured before. Before upgrade node name (rabbit working): `rabbit@376e265c649945fe87014f56bf054fe7`. After upgrade node name: `rabbit@upd-web`. The node name is defined in /etc/hosts and remains unchanged. The hostname is also the same as before: `rabbit@upd-web`. So I don't know why is it trying to connect to a different node name (the hostname). From what I see it cannot resolve the new node name (evidently).

Now, the configuration file remained the same as prior to the upgrade. The old format is still supported, per documentation.

Before/after upgrade config:

```
[ { kernel, [ { inet_dist_listen_min, 6150 }, { inet_dist_listen_max, 6150 } ] }, { rabbit, [ {tcp_listeners, [{'0.0.0.0', 5672},{'::1', 5672}]}, { cluster_nodes, { [ 'rabbit@f681cc63b892eecff1fa91a9f1ddbb9b','rabbit@376e265c649945fe87014f56bf054fe7' ], disc } } , { cluster_partition_handling, autoheal } ] } ].
```

hosts file (unchanged since before rabbit upgrade attempt):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       upd-web

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.56.104 376e265c649945fe87014f56bf054fe7
127.0.0.1       376e265c649945fe87014f56bf054fe7
```

The newly generated config file states the following:

```
 node           : rabbit@upd-web
 home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
 config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
 cookie hash    : iGIHB+jl59ul7YFrqAFIZQ==
 log(s)         : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@upd-web.log
                : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@upd-web_upgrade.log
 database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@upd-web
```

...while the old one referenced the old (and correct) node name:

```
node           : rabbit@376e265c649945fe87014f56bf054fe7
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
cookie hash    : iGIHB+jl59ul7YFrqAFIZQ==
log            : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@376e265c649945fe87014f56bf054fe7.log
sasl log       : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@376e265c649945fe87014f56bf054fe7-sasl.log
database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@376e265c649945fe87014f56bf054fe7
```

How can I make `RabbitMQ` reference the correct node name/database?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I needed to modify `rabbitmq-env` (it was customized before upgrade). Specifically:

```
RABBITMQ_NAME_TYPE=-sname
[ "x" = "x$HOSTNAME" ] && HOSTNAME=`env hostname`
```

I changed `env hostname` command substitution with another that puts the string assigned to `localhost`, from my `/etc/hosts`.